# Animate embedded UIWebView frame property

Tags: animation, uiview, uiwebview, frame

after a long search with no results,
maybe someone knows an answer to the following problem:

I have a UIView which contains a UIWebView as a subview. The UIView is just a wrapper, so that I can place buttons, etc. on top of the UIWebView.
I now want to animate the resizing and repositioning of the UIView AND the UIWebView simultaniously. I want it to look like it was just a UIWebView being resized.
I tried various animation techniques: block/commit, implicit/explicit,
for example like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"zoomIn" context:nil];  
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  

myWrapperUIView.frame = CGRect(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 500.0);  
myUIWebView.frame = CGRect(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 500.0);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

but I always get the result that the UIView animates kind of right, but the UIWebView inside just instantly switches to the new frame, so if I zoom from a bigger frame there is empty space around the UIWebView which shrinks during the animation.

I also tried an embedded animation for the UIWebView, but same result.

My Question is:
Is there a way to animate both Views simultaniously, so that at each point in time the UIWebWill be filling the UIView?

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: Have u solved the above mentioned query??? As i am also having the same issue... Plz let me know how u solved it...

Answer (score 1):

use  CGAffineTransform and scale the view using transform property, it will do the job.

```
myWrapperUIView.frame = CGRect(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 500.0);  
myUIWebView.frame = CGRect(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 500.0);
self.window.userInteractionEnabled =NO;
myWrapperUIView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
myUIWebView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATIONDURATION animations:^{
    myWrapperUIView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
    myUIWebView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      self.window.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}];
```

HOPE THIS HELPS,

Answer (score 0):

You must set the autoresizing mask for your web view.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

`@property(nonatomic) UIViewAutoresizing autoresizingMask`